Is it okay to flatten hierarchical data in MongoDB and repeat data in the documents
I'm trying to model the data as follows. Is this good practice or is there a better way so that I don't have to repeat the data in the checklist collection.
/*  technical book 1
      reference number
        subject area
          topic
            checklist1
              note1
              note2
              note3
              note4
              //many more notes
            checklist2
              note1
              note2
              note3
              //many more notes
            checklist3
              note1
              note2
              note3
              //many more notes
*/
// the note document structure - there could be many thousands of notes
[
    {
        _id: 8172931,
        noteTitle: "my 1st note title",
        noteText: "something interesting",
        noteRef: "other information",
        belongsTo: 27, //this is the checklistId
    },
    {
        _id: 8172932,
        noteTitle: "my 2nd note title",
        noteText: "something interesting",
        noteRef: "other information",
        belongsTo: 28, //this is the checklistId
    },
];

// the checklist document structure - there will be about 1000 checklists

[
    {
        _id: 27,
        checklistName: "1st checklist name",
        checklistTopic: "a topic",
        checklistSubject: "a subject",
        checklistRefNum: "f-38",
        checklistBookName: "the book that the checklist belongs to",
    },
    {
        _id: 28,
        checklistName: "2nd checklist name", //this will be unique
        checklistTopic: "a topic", //this will be repeated
        checklistSubject: "a subject", //this will be repeated
        checklistRefNum: "g-32", //this will be repeated
        checklistBookName: "the book that the checklist belongs to", //this will be repeated
    },
];


The UI for the app will display a list of notes when the user has selected a single checklist. The checklists will be displayed based on the selection of
BookName
RefNum
Subject
Topic

Thus the query for the checklists will be... (UI will update on user selection)
const agg = [
  {
    '$match': {
      'checklistBookName': 'example name', 
      'checklistRefNum': 'f-38', 
      'checklistSubject': 'a subject', 
      'checklistTopic': 'a topic'
    }
  }
];

const coll = client.db('databaseName').collection('checklists');
const cursor = coll.aggregate(agg);
const result = await cursor.toArray();


The corresponding notes will be retrieved then based on the checklist that they belong too. i.e. find all notes with the belongsTo = the checklist ID.
Is this good practice or is there a better way?

The note document field belongsTo: 27, //this is the checklistId - does a note belong to one checklist only or can belong to multiple checklists?

Yes a Note belongs to only one checklist.

//this will be repeated - these fields, how do they relate to the checklist (as they are its attributes). What is their relationship and how you are going to use this data, and these are the issues you need to know. For example, a "topic" is related to multiple checklists and this is a 1:N relationship. And, what are the attributes of a topic? What is its significance in your application? These are things you need to be clear about.

One checklist will belong to a topic which belongs to a subject area which belongs to a reference number which in turn belongs to a technical book as per the hierarchy. These are only single attributes.
